# C++ Create two variables with overlapping memory

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have two `structs`, `Rect` and `Point`. I cannot change their implementation, regrettably.

The definition of Rect is:

```
typedef struct Rect
{
    int x, y;
    int w, h;
} Rect;
```

The definition of `Point` is:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

I would like to keep a single Rect, effectively, but keep the `w`/`h` members hidden.

I wondered if it was possible to create a Point object using the same address in memory such that the `x`/`y` memory is shared between each object?

I have tried using `placement new`, and it didn't seem to work, as well as reassigning the address, which obviously didn't work either.

Anyone have any ideas? I know this probably isn't the best practice, but it would be a neat trick and make things a lot simpler to work with.

hnefatl

Comment: You mean like in a [`union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)?

Comment: `typedef struct R { } R;` this looks like C rather than C++

Comment: By the way you don't need `typedef` in C++, the structure names can be used as types.

Comment: It seems the what you need is a union

Comment: .. to save how many bits? How many GByte is your memory? Besides the is it possible question I would not bother - maybe in some extreme embedded environment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `union` always takes the largest memory, doesnt it? This is the opposite of what is asked!?

Comment: If you want to keep your code straightforward and portable, this is (1) not possible and (2) not needed.

Comment: You say you want to make things "simpler"? Then this is *not* the way to go, it will make things *much* more complicated, hard to maintain, and risk your code getting on http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: You might need something like this, reusing memory for different structures, if you are coding for a system with extremely limited memory, and I don't mean a megabyte or two, I mean a few *kilo* bytes.

Comment: Based on my own experience, I claim that it wouldn't actually be a neat trick, nor would it make things any simpler to work with. Things of different types are best kept separate, even if they happen to contain similar amounts of similarly named things.

Comment: You should look into making a new type that can take a `Rect` to construct from and is convertable to a `Rect` via a cast operator. That way you can make your own type however you want without changing the original types while staying compatible.

Comment: I've decided it's impossible - I'll post an answer saying as much as soon as I can (less than 10 rep :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and answers, it seems this is impossible. Oh well, would've been a nice trick with pointers!

I'll just keep the rect and not hide the `w` and `h` members.

Thanks to all who answered :)

hnefatl

P.S. The code I'm using is written in C, and I'm using C++ to interact with it. Sorry, forgot to mention that :/

P.P.S. Thanks for the link explaining a union Joachim, I'd never got round to learning about them!

Answer (score 3):

You should hide your Rect inside your own class, providing the interface you need. Something like:

```
class MyRect
{
    private:
        Rect _rect;

    public:
        MyRect(const Rect& rect);

        int& x() { return _rect.x; }
        int& y() { return _rect.y; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ has the concept of layout compatible.  Your `Point` and `Rect` classes are layout-compatible as they have a common initial prefix, and they are standard-layout (or plain old data in C++03).

This means

```
Rect r = {1,2,3,4};
Point* p = &reinterpret_cast<Point*>(&r);
```

generates a `Point` pointer `p` that points to the `x` and `y` fields of the Rect `r`.  Modifying the `x` and `y` fields of `*p` will modify the values in `r`, and modifying `r.x` and `r.y` will modify the values in `*p`.  Well, sort of.

The downside is the concept of aliasing and strict aliasing.  If you turn off strict aliasing in your compiler, it will lose some optimizations, but the above will work.

To get it to work with strict aliasing working you need to store both your `Rect` and your `Point` in a union:

```
union MyUnion {
  Rect r;
  Point p;
};
MyUnion u = Rect{1,2,3,4};
```

and now `p.x` and `p.y` refer to `r.x` and `r.y` in any context where "it is permitted to inspect the
    common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of
    the complete type of the union is visible".  So where `MyUnion` can be seen, you are safe -- but where it cannot be seen, the compiler is free to treat a pointer-to-`Point` modifying `x` as not being able to modify the pointer-to-`Rect`'s `x`.  This is important for optimization purposes, as without it reordering unchanged sub expressions becomes next to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna hide `w` and `h`, maybe you can create an "ad hoc" `Point` based on `Rect` values and use this structure... then, if `x` and `y` can be different than originals you can set current values to original `Rect` variable:

```
Rect original_rect;

// ...

Point point;
point.x = original_rect.x;
point.y = original_rect.y;

// code that use Point instead of Rect
// ...

// Set current values to original variable
original_rect.x = point.x;
original_rect.y = point.y;
```

On the other hand, if you need to use `Rect`class and hide `w`and `h` at the same time... you cannot do it